# Recursive functions in python

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.3

I just started learning python after scheme. Is recursion like `sum+=alist[0]+sumup(alist[1:])` not allowed? I get the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

The code:

```
m=int(input())
c=list(map(int,input().split()))
x,y=map(int,input().split())
sum=0

def sumup(alist):
    global sum
    if alist==[]:
        return 0
    else:
        if sum<x:
            sum+=alist[0]+sumup(alist[1:])
        elif sum>=x:
            return sum
        elif sum>y:
            return 0

sumup(c)
```

Comment: what are `x` and `y` suppose to mean to this function?

Comment: I want to sum up the elements in the array such that they are bounded by x and y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your recursive function returns `None` for the case where `alist` is not empty and `sum < x` is `True`.

You'll need to get rid of the `global sum` here however, as you are going to end up adding to that value whatever you return from recursive calls. That'll only lead to doubling the value.

At most, make `sum` a parameter to the function to pass along the value to recursive calls. You didn't provide us with sample input and output, so it is *very* hard to determine what you are trying to achieve with the function.

Last, but not least, the `elif sum > y:` branch will never be executed, as one of `sum < x` and `sum >= x` will always be `True`.

Comment: So generally, recursion does not happen with global variables?

Comment: No, mixing globals and return values is not a good idea; recursion just makes it worse.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot a return statement in the `if sum <x:` clause:

```
        if sum<x:
            sum+=alist[0]+sumup(alist[1:])
```

should be

```
        if sum<x:
            sum+=alist[0]+sumup(alist[1:])
            return sum
```

and also, another case - if `sum <= y` you are not returning anything. (You might want to get rid of `elif sum>y` clause, as that would never happen. )

Comment: it will never even get to the if before that.  he probably wanted a `return sum` at the end of the function

Comment: The tests agains `y` are entirely redundant, as `sum` is either going to be smaller, or equal or larger than `x`. The third branch is never going to be touched upon, it doesn't matter what value `y` has, ever.